# Undo model namespacing causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I had both namespaced controllers and models like this:

controller: Modules::Insurances
model: Modules::Insurances

This worked fine, but I want to remove the namespaced model back to normal, but keep the namespaced controller. I have removed all the references to "Modules::" in the models and also in all the activerecord queries in the controller to the model. When I visit the page, it returns this error:

```
Expected /***/app/models/modules/ins_insurance.rb to define Modules::InsInsurance
```

What should I do more to remove the namespaced model?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the error is that rails is expecting the name of the class declared inside the file `modules/ins_insurance.rb` to be `Modules::InsInsurance` -- the filename must match the class name (after a little conversion thanks to the Inflector's `underscore` and `classify` methods: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/underscore).  So name the file back to `insurance.rb` and you should be OK.

On a broader topic, I can only think you'll run into problems sooner or later by using a sub-directory called `modules` -- at the very least it's confusing between the Ruby keyword `Module`.  If you're looking for a place to put general purpose code, use `app/lib` then `require` the file as needed.  Namespacing is a fine thing to do, but you'll end up fighting with Rails unless you go with the flow.  (Lesson learned the hard way ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get rid of the "Modules::" part, because it's not a namespace anymore. The modules path is now loaded as autoload_path in application.rb. So I thought I just could remove all references to Modules:: in the model?

Comment: Nope. Class names and file paths and names are bound together in the Rails world ... it's really a foundation of many, many, many of the features of the framework, and while sometimes a little opaque, they are what make coding in Rails seem magic.  If you're still working your way along the path of leanring "the Rails way", perhaps you could ask another question here that asked "I want to do X in order to accomplish Y.  Is this a good idea, and what's the best way to do it?".  Lotsa ninjas here are happy to help.